# How to show a datatable when pressing a button?

Tags: r

I want to show a datatable that is in a sql database after pressing a button exactly as it is on this [link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), How to use observeEvent in conjunction with renderDT?

```r
#ATTEMPT 1

library(RMariaDB)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
actionButton("datatable1", "Button"),
DTOutput("datatable2"))

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){

plotsettings<-reactiveValues()
     observeEvent(input$datatable1, {
      localuserpassword="MYPASSWORD"
      storiesDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='user', password=localuserpassword, dbname='DBNAME', host='localhost') #connect to the database
      query= "SELECT *  FROM TABLENAME" #select everything from the table
      rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,query)#send the command
      plotSettings<-dbFetch(rs) #transform to data.frame and store in plotSettings
            })
output$datatable2<-renderDT(plotSettings) 
})
```

I have to use the DT package to be able to select a specific datatable line and edit it.